# How to get current date to particular format

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am new to iOS.

I got wrong format when getting NSLog for date.

Output is `2013-12-06 18:30:00 +0000` but I need to display in `dd/mm/yyyy` format.

Here is my code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);

NSString *str=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
NSDate *date=[dateFormatter dateFromString:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];

[dateFormatter release];
```

Comment: Ok, what is wrong with your code? What is the output of the nslogs?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking? It seems you've got what you want with the 2nd logging statement... http://i.imgur.com/qFgiIz7.png

Comment: When you log an `NSDate` object you will always get that format. It's only for debugging and it is correct.

Comment: nslog(date==>%@,date) i got like this "2013-12-06 18:30:00 +0000" but my format should me like this"06/12/2013" please help me to get in that format @rmaddy

Comment: The 5th line of code you posted gives you what you want. What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Don't make it complex,this should work.

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
 NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

May this help you.

```
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[format setDateFormat:@"dd/MMM/yyyy"];
NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSString *dateString = [format stringFromDate:now];
NSLog(@"%@",dateString);
```

Enjoy coding

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSLog(@"%@",date);
```

*Above code will give you following output:*
**2014-11-27 10:44:43 +0000**

*But whenever you want to set date in proper format by removing time then follow the below code*,

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@",dateString);
```

*The Output will be :* **27/11/2014**